# Node winston cannot support multiple file transport?

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I want to show error logs in one file and all logs in another file. To do that, I wrote two file transports which give the following error on compilation:

```
 'use strict';

var winston = require('winston'),   
  config = require('./config');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)({level:'debug',handleExceptions: true,prettyPrint: true,silent:false,timestamp: true,colorize: true,json: false}),
  new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './server/logs/bv_common.log',level:'debug',maxsize: 1024000,maxFiles: 10, handleExceptions: true,json: false}),
  new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './server/logs/bv_error.log',level:'debug',maxsize: 1024000,maxFiles: 10, handleExceptions: true,json: false,level:'error'})

]
  });


module.exports = logger;
```

Result:

```
   [ 'Error: Transport already attached: file',
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple log files with Winston?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045891/multiple-log-files-with-winston)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17374968/362536

Comment: FYI, the last transport has the 'level' defined twice.

Answer (score 11):

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
exitOnError: false, //don't crash on exception
transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)({level:'debug',handleExceptions: true,prettyPrint: true,silent:false,timestamp: true,colorize: true,json: false}),
  new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './server/logs/' + config.appname +'_common.log',name:'file.all',level:'debug',maxsize: 1024000,maxFiles: 10, handleExceptions: true,json: false}),
  new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: './server/logs/' + config.appname +'_error.log',name:'file.error',level:'error',maxsize: 1024000,maxFiles: 10, handleExceptions: true,json: false})
]
  });
```

The above code , especially with name parameter for shared transport, we can use multiple file transports for loggers.

Answer (score 9):

You are getting this error because you are not providing a 'name' attribute to your file transports.